# Find the sum of the squared solutions from the following system: $x^{y^2-3y+3}=x \text{ and } x+2y=5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, systems-of-equations

> Find the sum of the squared solutions from the following system: $\begin{cases}x^{y^2-3y+3}=x \\x+2y=5\end{cases}$

The book I'm working from gives the right solution (out of 6, it is multiple choice) $S=\frac{125}{4}$, where $S$ is the required sum. However, I'm not quite getting there, and I think I'm mistakenly calculating the same solution twice. What I did was:
$$x+2y=5 \iff x = 5-2y \Rightarrow (5-2y)^{y^2+3y+3} = 5-2y \Rightarrow \\[3ex] \Rightarrow \begin{cases}(5-2y)^{y^2-3y+3-1}=1, \ \text{for } y \neq \frac{5}{2} \Rightarrow y^2-3y+2 =0 \iff y\in\{1, 2\} \Rightarrow x\in\{3, 1\}  \\ 5-2y = 1 \iff y = 2\Rightarrow x =1 \\ \text{(I think this is the solution I already got, so is this step useless?} \\ \text{Could I simply divide by } (5-2y) \text{ assuming it is not } 0?)\\ 5-2y = 0 \iff y=\frac{5}{2}\Rightarrow x =0\end{cases}$$
Doing this yields me a much smaller sum: $\frac{25}{4} + 10 + 5$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $x^m=x$ if $m=1$ or $x=1,$ or, possibly, depending on definitions, $x=0.$

Comment: The solutions are pairs, so what does the question mean by the squared solutions?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews $\sum_{(x,y)\in A} (x^2+y^2)$, where $A$ is the group containing all the pairs that are solution for the system.

Comment: Okay, well, that's a terrible misuse of language. $x$ isn't "a solution," it is one element of the solution. (But that was going to be my guess of the meaning.)

Comment: You are going to get nowhere substituting $x=(5-2y),$ I suspect.

Comment: Wouldn't that be $\frac{25}{4} + 3^2+1^2 +1^2+2^2+1^2+2^2 = \frac{25}{4} + 10 + 5 + 5 = \frac{25 + 80}{4}$ which is still smaller than $\frac{125}{4}$?

Comment: I think your answer is right. No idea how the answer set got $\frac{125}4.$ Had a thought they had double counted $(x,y)=(1,2),$ but that add up to $\frac{125}4.$ You'd have to double count $(3,1)$ to get $\frac{125}4,$ and that is less likely.

Comment: Yes, I deleted that comment already. @j__n

Comment: Now that you mention doubling the solution $(3, 1)$, isn't $(-1, 3)$ also a solution? This is more of a rhetorical question, because it is, but how would one even get to it?

Comment: $x^p = x$ if $p = 1$, or $x = 1$, or $x = 0$ and $p > 0$, or $x=-1$ and $p$ an odd integer.

Comment: Ah, yes, $(-1,3)$ is probably the extra solution. As a rule, for this sort of problem, I don't define $u^v$ for $u<0,$ because the domain of $(u,v)$ with $u^v$ defined would be very strange. But you can define it.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing (-1,3). -1 to the power of an odd number is -1, and -1 + 2y = 5 gives y = 3. Since 3^2 - 3(3) + 3 is odd, (-1,3) should work too.